# How to make text "Passed" and progress bar appear in line in smaller views?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made the following design using Bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container-fluid parent-vertical-align">
    <div class="container-fluid child-vertical-align" style="width: 99%;">
      <div class="row row-centered">

        <!-- block 1 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 center-block">
            <div>
                <!-- Thumb-nail Image -->
                <div>
                    <img src="img/a.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <!-- Status bars -->
                <br/><br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        Passed <br/><br/> 
                        Failed <br/><br/>
                        Skipped <br/>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-9">

                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 80%">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 80%">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 60%">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--  custom css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css"> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here is my custom css file

```
body,html
{
    height: 100%;
}
.parent-vertical-align{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.child-vertical-align{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 90%;
}

.img-responsive{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
}
.center-block{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row-centered{
    text-align:center;
}
.progress{
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

The problem is, when I resize my chrome window, the design progress bar goes to the next line. Please refer to this image:

[image]

I want it to be displayed exactly to the right side of the text. 
It does work on larger screens, but doesn't work on smaller ones.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try the media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap provides media query class acccording to diffrent screen sizes

use

```
col-xs-4 for maximum 768px

col-sm-4 for 768px to 992px
col-md-4 for 992px to 1200px
col-lg-4 for greater than 1200px
```

```css
body,html
{
    height: 100%;
}
.parent-vertical-align{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.child-vertical-align{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 90%;
}

.img-responsive{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
}
.center-block{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row-centered{
    text-align:center;
}
.progress{
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container-fluid parent-vertical-align">
    <div class="container-fluid child-vertical-align" style="width: 99%;">
      <div class="row row-centered">

        <!-- block 1 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 center-block">
            <div>
                <!-- Thumb-nail Image -->
                <div>
                    <img src="img/a.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <!-- Status bars -->
                <br/><br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        Passed <br/><br/> 
                        Failed <br/><br/>
                        Skipped <br/>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">

                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 75%">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 75%">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width:75%">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--  custom css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css"> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: also mention, what changes you have made. so OP can understand easily

Comment: i forget that sorry and updated my question thanks for advice @UbiquitousDevelopers

Comment: did you clear your cache?? because your can check in this snippet its working fine with every screen. the reason of not working could be affected by other  css codes.

Comment: Hi, its working :) Thanks :) I removed the sm one, because its going on new line at 800px